# Filters (StopWords, Stemmer...) not applied in ElasticSearch index

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a problem with elasticsearch (java client) as I am not capable of storing the info as I want to store it. This is what I have done:

First, I created my settings. Setting are applied in the index creation.

```
Settings settings = settingsBuilder().loadFromSource(jsonBuilder()
    .startObject()
        .startObject("analysis")
            .startObject("char_filter")
                .startObject("&_to_and")
                    .field("type", "mapping")
                    .array("mappings", "&=> and ", "\"=> . ")
                .endObject()
            .endObject()
            .startObject("filter")
                .startObject("my_stopwords")
                    .field("type", "stop")
                    .field("stopwords_path", "stopwords/stop_" + lang + ".txt")
                .endObject()
                .startObject("stemmer")
                    .field("type", "stemmer")
                    .field("language", language)
                .endObject()
            .endObject()
            .startObject("analyzer")
                .startObject("my_analyzer")
                    .field("type", "custom")
                    .array("char_filter", "html_strip", "&_to_and")
                    .field("tokenizer", "standard")
                    .array("filter",  "stemmer", "lowercase", "my_stopwords")
                .endObject()
            .endObject()
        .endObject()
    .endObject().string()).build();
```

As you can see, I created my setting to have my own "stop_words" and a few more things to consider before inserting anything in the index.

Apart from this, I created as well the following mapping for the field in the documents that'll be created in such index:

```
XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject()
            .startObject("properties")
                .startObject("words")
                    .field("type", "string")
                    .field("index", "analyzed")
                    .field("analyzer", "my_analyzer")
                .endObject()
            .endObject()
        .endObject();
```

Both things are applied when creating the index, like this:

```
CreateIndexRequestBuilder createIndexRequestBuilder = client.admin()
    .indices()
    .prepareCreate(indexName)
    .setSettings(settings)
    .addMapping(documentType, getWordstype());
```

The problem is that I can't see that all those rules are applied in the index as I've been having a look at the info stored in the index and nothing has been applied. Am I missing a step or something? Am I creating the index properly? Filter are ok?

Comment: I'd like to know where do you store your stop words? Are they in `ES_HOME/config/stopwords` folder? It would be also good if you could post raw JSON how built index settings look like. :) I don't know Java client well, but it seems that you're creating your index properly and filter are applied correctly.

Comment: The settings are applied to the index, but when inserting or updating documents, for some reason the the filters are not used. The lists of stop words are in the directory mentioned.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and add index settings once you've added at least one document? That would help a lot.

Comment: Both _settings and _mappings if possible. Add this to your question.

Comment: {"rssvectorindex":{"settings":{"index":{"creation_date":"1447427043189","uuid":"j8f96g2gSIi_KBNJP-xQRg","number_of_replicas":"1","analysis":{"char_filter":{"&_to_and":{"type":"mapping","mappings":["&=> and ","\"=> . "]}},"analyzer":{"my_analyzer":{"type":"custom","char_filter":["html_strip","&_to_and"],"filter":["stemmer","lowercase","my_stopwords"],"tokenizer":"standard"}},"filter":{"my_stopwords":{"type":"stop","stopwords_path":"stopwords/stop_es.txt"},"stemmer":{"type":"stemmer","language":"spanish"}}},"number_of_shards":"5","version":{"created":"1070299"}}}}}root@ip-10-37-227-56:

Comment: settings and mapping apparently are defined in the index but when inserting or updating new documents in such index, the settings and mapping are ignored

Comment: You forgot to add `_mappings` there. That would give more details.

Comment: {"rssvectorindex":{"mappings":{"categoryDocument":{"properties":{"words":{"type":"string","analyzer":"my_analyzer"}}}}}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know what you're seeing as an issue. In fact it's not. Everything's fine with your mappings and settings.

You're most likely looking for removed stop words in your `_source` field. This field always has unmodified data, it just represents what was pushed into Elasticsearch index, nothing else.

If you would like to know whether your analyzer works or not, you have to use `_analyze` API. This is example how to use it:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/rssvectorindex/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&pretty=true&text=your test data with stop words'
```

This will produce a list of tokens for your text. If your stop words are removed from it. It means your analyzer works just fine.